# How could I save my spliited nifi data as separate file inti my local machine

Tags: parallel-processing, apache-nifi, stack-overflow

How to divide single file into multiple files and store them separately in same location using nifi processors , I devided data into multiple files using splitRecorder . NowI want to **store them separately in same location**

Answer (score 0):

First, you want to create logic to split 2 files into 2 different paths. You can use `RouteOnAttribute` Processor for that. Then you can create a new attribute to check your **UUID**: `${filename:contains('add one of your uuid')}`.

**Example:**
`eg: ${uuid:contains('b1d00168-a2ec-4d2a-b93d-8a61008c662a')}`

Then your 2 files are divided into 2 paths. Then you can add the `updateAttribute` processor for one of the paths. Here you can update your file name.

`${filename:prepend(${now():toNumber()})}`

---

[image]

[image]

[image]